# How to pass extra properties to a struct in Golang? Like you would in Typescript

Tags: typescript, go, struct

I need to recreate a Typescript interface using Golang. This interface uses a `[k: string]: any;` key to indicate that the interface could have more properties than the ones declared inside the interface.

```typescript
export interface MyInterface {
  first: string;
  second: string;
  [k: string]: any;
}
```

How could archive this in Golang? Right now my struct looks like this:

```go
type MyStruct struct {
    First  string `json:"first"`
    Second string `json:"second"`
}
```

This works fine with the two keys, but how could I do something like this:

```go
var ms MyStruct

ms.First = "first"
ms.Second = "second"
ms.Foo = "bar"
ms.Bar = false
```

Answer (score 4):

Go is a statically typed language, all fields you intend to use must be declared at compile time.

The closest you can do is add a map field to the struct in which you can store additional values.

For example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    First  string                 `json:"first"`
    Second string                 `json:"second"`
    Props  map[string]interface{} `json:"props"`
}
```

Using it:

```
var ms = MyStruct{Props: map[string]interface{}{}}

ms.First = "first"
ms.Second = "second"
ms.Props["Foo"] = "bar"
ms.Props["Bar"] = false

fmt.Println(ms)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ggin3cEd0qJ)):

```
{first second map[Bar:false Foo:bar]}
```

**Note:** Using reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) you can create structs with "dynamic" fields (defined at runtime), but you still can't refer to those fields as if they would be defined at compile time.